# WP_REST_REQUEST: how to add "_embed" to request parameters

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I added this function to my wordpress REST API to have a custom endpoint

```
function getSettimanaEventi(){
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/tribe_events' );
$request['_embed'] = '1';
$request['filter[meta_query][0][key]'] = '_EventStartDate';
$request['filter[meta_query][0][value][0]'] = '2017-07-03 00:00:00';
$request['filter[meta_query][0][value][1]'] = '2017-07-09 00:00:00';
$request['filter[meta_query][0][compare]'] = 'BETWEEN';
$request['filter[meta_query][0][type]'] = 'DATE';


$response = rest_do_request( $request );
return $response;
```

i got a response but there isn't the embedded content.

I know the parameters with a leading '_' are private but i need embedded content.
How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i found is to add the "_embed" parameter to the url (when you call it from Postman for example) and delete it from the request parameters

Comment: This in Postman
http://prntscr.com/fdd12v

And this in functions.php
    function getSettimanaEventi(){
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/tribe_events' );
$request['filter[meta_query][0][key]'] = '_EventStartDate';
$request['filter[meta_query][0][value][0]'] = '2017-07-03 00:00:00';
$request['filter[meta_query][0][value][1]'] = '2017-07-09 00:00:00';
$request['filter[meta_query][0][compare]'] = 'BETWEEN';
$request['filter[meta_query][0][type]'] = 'DATE';


$response = rest_do_request( $request );
return $response;

Answer (score 1):

This works for me perfectly

```
global $wp_rest_server;
$request = new WP_Rest_Request('GET', '/wp/v2/posts');
$response = rest_do_request($request);
$response = $wp_rest_server->response_to_data($response, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Update - this doesn't seem to be working. I'll update if I figure it out.)

You must set it in the super global like this:

```
function getSettimanaEventi () {
  // Set super global to simulate request param
  $_GET['_embed'] = 1;
  $request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/tribe_events' );
  $request['filter[meta_query][0][key]'] = '_EventStartDate';
  $request['filter[meta_query][0][value][0]'] = '2017-07-03 00:00:00';
  $request['filter[meta_query][0][value][1]'] = '2017-07-09 00:00:00';
  $request['filter[meta_query][0][compare]'] = 'BETWEEN';
  $request['filter[meta_query][0][type]'] = 'DATE';
  $response = rest_do_request( $request );
  // cleanup after
  unset($_GET['_embed']);
  return $response;
}
```

I found this info in this ticket for WP-API:
https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2857